# Cartoon movie where the main character had a robotic arm

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

During the 90's I saw parts of a science-fiction cartoon on TV. I don't remember for sure, but the graphics resembled *[Heavy Metal](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082509/)*, and I think it was American, but again, I'm not sure.

What I do remember is that the main character had a robot arm that looked just like a regular one. I think the humans were at war with robots controlled by an evil overlord, and someone believed the main character was also a robot because of his arm.

Another relevant memory was related to the bad guy (or one of the bad guys): in the end, it turns out it was a bratty teen who thought it was a game or who didn't realize exactly what he did.

---

**[edit]** Based on the feedback received so far, I need to add that:

- this was a cartoon, not anime / japanese animation.
- It was a movie, not a cartoon series.
- The robots were more like androids / humanoid robots, not mecha.

I also remembered a female protagonist. She's the one who notices the main character had a robotic arm after he has some sort of accident and robotic parts become visible beneath his arm skin.

Do these details sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: I don't know if this will help at all or not, but by the description, two cartoons come to mind. They are both Japanese animation, and both are big names though, so it may not be what you are looking for. The first is Tri-Gun. In this though, some of the bad guys are robots and some are "plant creatures"... the second is a smoother animation called Big O! It is more mech on mech, but he has a wristwatch he uses to summon and control Big O that you might be remembering.

Comment: I know (and seen) both Trigun and Big O, but this was not an anime, it was a cartoon. And the robots were not mecha, they were more like humandoid robots

Comment: Is it the [Bots Master (1993-94)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bots_Master)? [IMDB link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0124232/) The [animation](https://www.google.com/search?q=bots%20master%20pictures&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) sort of looks like same style as Heavy metal. ZZ the main character has lots of robotic devices to aid him (and one is on his arm) And he fights lots of robots with a team of robots of his own.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sounds like The Body Electric.
A 1985 animated feature produced by Canadian animation studio Atkinson Film-Arts (whose credits include the movie Heavy Metal) featuring music from Rush.
The hero reveals he has a robotic arm eventually, there's a female side kick and the bad guy is a bratty teen as suggested.
There's a version on YouTube here...