# Name of a cartoon in the late 90's/early 2000's about a man with a robot arm he couldn't control?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

So this may sound like *Inspector Gadget*, but there was a cartoon about a guy with a robotic arm which would sometimes turn into a blaster or a laser cutter or something useful, but I can't remember much more than that... It may have taken place in a desert (ice or sand) again can't be sure.

It wasn't Japanese; it was either American or English.

Comment: Are you sure you can't remember anything else? That description seems quite broad

Comment: Can you remember anything about the art style? Were all the characters humans?

Comment: Sorry - can't remember much more - They WERE all humans if I remember correctly, but I think the main character sometimes lost control of his arm and he had to use a certain item, like it was cursed or something??? Sorry I can't be much more help :/

Answer (score 5):

Is it like [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36437/)?  It sounds very similar. The answer to that question was "The body electric".

Comment: WOW - thanks I can see you've really taken time and gone out of your way to help, I'm sure that must have been what I'm thinking of!

Comment: If this is the correct answer, when you return, please click on the checkmark below the voting buttons to verify it.

Comment: VTC as very likely duplicate

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of the English dub of *Trigun*.

[image: Dark Horse cover of "Trigun" issue #1]

The main character, Vash the Stampede, had a cybernetic prosthetic left arm that hid a pistol/submachine gun:

[image: Close-up of Vash's arm gun, showing how the hand has detached at the wrist to expose the barrel and grip of the gun which were hidden in the arm]

In a few scenes where he lost control of himself, his [right arm](https://trigun.fandom.com/wiki/Angel_Arm) would turn into a powerful organic laser cannon:

[image: Vash's right arm has shaped the "angel arm" cannon, which looks like a life-sized figure in white, complete with wings, containing a glowing golden orb and outlined in blue energy filaments]