# What was that movie with the man with the robot arm?

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a while ago, I was probably around the age of 7-9. Around those times I used to love watching movies with my stepdad. I remember this one movie, I totally forgot the name which was about:

- A man who worked in a factory for like a 'dictator like utopian society' (all in my words).
- He gets his arm cut off or injured during his working in this factory, so they replace it with an artificial robot arm.
- It was probably in the future.
- After his arm gets changed with a robot arm, the factory he works for no longer wants him.
- He shortly after goes to this rebellion, I forget what they they were rebelling though, heh.

Anyways, anyone know what movie I'm talking about?

Comment: Can you elaborate when you were around 7-9? Was it last year? 10 years ago? 50? Also, although you've included some good details, your question  is still quite broad. Could you add *any* more details?

Comment: Additionally, you've tagged this as "AI", however, there doesn't seem to be any actual AI elements you've mentioned (a robotic arm is not necessarily AI).

Comment: This sounds like a really garbled version of "I, Robot"

Comment: "Gentlemen, we can rebuild him. We have the technology..."

Comment: Sounds like I, Robot to me to, just with the characters of Spooner and Sonny merged into one.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - With elements of Elysium thrown in for good measure, specifically the main character getting hurt in a factory, a cybernetic suit, joining the Rebellion, etc.

Comment: Well, if the OP is now about 10-12 years old and 2013 is "a while ago" for them, maybe it is Elysium XD

Comment: " 'dictator like utopian society' (all in my words)". If it's your words, why did you put quotes around it?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - When you're mis-remembering things, it's easy to conflate old with new.

Comment: Possibly the same movie asked about here: [Cartoon movie where the main character had a robotic arm](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36437/cartoon-movie-where-the-main-character-had-a-robotic-arm)

Comment: Identified as "[The Body Electric](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVZ5cKHHuhw)"

Comment: I wouldn't even attempt to answer this without knowing when "around the age of 7-9" was.

Comment: @Mooz I'm 14 now, so about 7 yeara ago.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh No, this was a 'real life' movie, and focus less on asking why I did this and that and more on actually answering the question.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo This wasn't over 10 yrs ago.

Comment: I think an important question is "Did you see this at the cinema or on TV", because seeing it at the cinema drastically reduces the list of movies it could possibly be. If you saw it on TV, doesn't really matter when it was made. Also, if you can potentially remember who played the lead role (Or any well-known actors/actresses), that would immensely useful.

Comment: @Broly Wow, 14. I feel like I have to act like the "cool" uncle now. Quick say some funky stuff... Er... "YOLO"! Do people still say that?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be the movie [Elysium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_(film))?  Dystopian Los Angeles factory worker Max is exposed to a lethal radiation dose during an industrial accident. He has a broken wrist from a previous encounter. His only hope for a cure is to sneak onto the space station Elysium and get to a med bay. To get there he has to work with an underground organization that grafts an exoskeleton to him and sends him to invade the space station. Movie came out in 2013 so it might be too recent.

Answer (score -1):

[*Hands of Steel*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091166/?ref_=nv_sr_1)?

[image: Movie poster for *Hands of Steel*]

> A cyborg is programmed to kill a scientist who holds the fate of mankind in his hands. He fails and hides in a diner in a desert run by a woman who likes him. The people who sent him are after him and so is the local arm wrestling champ.

I don't remember the whole movie. Just some vague memory about a guy with a robot arm and some arm wrestling scenes.

Comment: Could you maybe add in some more details as to why you think this is it?

Answer (score -5):

This sounds like The Long arm of Gil Hamilton by Larry Niven.
I read this over 40 years ago I don't remember how he lost his arm. He was a detective in Niven's known space.

Comment: Was it made into a movie?

Comment: Frankly this sounds *nothing* like any of the GIl Hamilton stories. Gil loses his arm in a mining accident in the belt with the co-owners of his mining ship. They are willing to keep him on but eventually he returns to Earth where he receives a new organic arm from the organ banks, and he joins the UN police force rather than starting a rebellion.

Comment: It wasn't over 10 years ago.