# 80/90s post-apocalyptic anime/cartoon about the destruction of a domed city

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I'm trying to identify an animated movie I saw in the early 90's. The art style I remember as being typical of the 80's era anime (round heads and eyes, not overly detailed surface) although I couldn't say for sure it was actually anime and not a western cartoon.

The key points that I remember was that a small party are trying to leave a domed city for some reason. There had been a war between humanity and robots so there was immense hostility towards robots.

Through the course of the movie, they meet a male character who assists with events but in the final climax the sleeve on his arm is raised and reveals that he is actually a cyborg, which causes a significant rift in the group. Shortly afterwards, the city is destroyed with (I think) the majority of the robotic opposition.

I'd peg the creation of the show to the 80's but it could have been from earlier, I don't believe it would be later than the early 90's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like _**[The Body Electric](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0220337/)** (1985).

From an [IMDB user review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw3067485/?ref_=tt_urv):

> "The Body Electric" is a short, but pretty rare made-for-TV cartoon from 1985, directed by the uncredited David Feiss. It was produced by the former company Atkinson Film-Arts.

The main IMDB plot summary reads as follows:

> **Red Sector A was a paradise...for a man's machines. The domed city was home to the last of the human race, where they lived in comfort, served by their robotic servants. Until one day a mysterious force turns the robots against their masters, and the machines cast the people out of Red Sector A into the wastelands outside.** Years later, the robots have collapsed into dust without human maintenance, leaving two young people - Woody and Andrea - to live in the city. But the city is on the verge of a exploding as the shield generator approaches meltdown. Andrea and Woody have a few hours to escape Red Sector A, but the unknown force that caused the revolution is still present, and has it's own plans for them.

As the plot summary explains, the main story takes place in a domed city, now a depopulated wasteland after robotic servants rose up against their human masters years earlier. The male lead, Woody, encounters the female lead, Andrea, while wandering through the city. They get along well initially, but she briefly becomes distrustful of him when it's revealed that he has a cybernetic arm, until he explains how he got it.

You can view that scene at around the 12:00 mark in the video below.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36437/cartoon-movie-where-the-main-character-had-a-robotic-arm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I remember the movie being distinctly more cartoony but this has to be it; watching it brought back quite a few details I'd forgotten (the just randomly wandering a decaying city vibe, the remote surveillance, necklace, even the 'master' ). Curiously, I've got absolutely no memory of the music! Thanks much.