# Help identifying this animation about a locked-down city overtaken by androids

Tags: story-identification, anime, androids, animation

I would've seen this in the early nineties. I think it was a movie, and only saw the end of it on TV (which probably means it wasn't new at the time).

There was a boy and a girl, and they were trying to escape a city that had been overtaken by androids. At the end, they were talking with what seemed to be the android in charge, won some kind of moral victory in their speech to it, and the androids all shut down and/or the walls keeping them in the city crumbled or exploded and they were able to escape.

The end titles had a sweet but sad song with female vocals, showing a montage of scenes from the movie.

As far as I can work out, it was not any Studio Ghibli production, and is definitely not Laputa. Though I'm pretty sure it was anime it *may* have been western style animation.

**Update**: I've just remembered an important detail! It turned out at the end that all these robots/androids were being controlled by a spoiled boy. It's possible I've actually made a dupe of this question, as the 'bubble' sounds familiar too:

[Story Identification: 1980s series about four characters who escape a post-apocalyptic city in a bubble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30491/story-identification-1980s-series-about-four-characters-who-escape-a-post-apoca?rq=1)

Comment: I was going to suggest Vexille (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vexille), but that came out in 2007.

Comment: This immediately made me think of "The Order to Stop Construction", from the anthology film Labyrinth Tales (known as "Neo Tokyo" in its American home video release). But the plot doesn't quite match, and that short film has a singular male protagonist.

Comment: I'm also thinking of one of the segments from Robot Carnival, another anthology film. Or possibly the Casshan: Robot Hunter OAV, which was presented as a movie compilation on American TV in the 90s. But I don't think either of those quite match either.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions, as you suspected they don't seem to be the one.

Comment: How was the city **"overtaken"** by androids? It was a mobile city, and it was fleeing the androids, but the androids caught up with it? Or was "overtaken" perhaps a typo for "taken over"?

Comment: @user14111 whichever one you prefer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is The Body Electric, as detailed in this other question: [Cartoon movie where the main character had a robotic arm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36437/cartoon-movie-where-the-main-character-had-a-robotic-arm)

So good to have finally found it! (It's not that great actually but it was driving me nuts).